# Reliable ways to identify pre-warming on iOS

Tags: ios, ios-prewarming

Are there any reliable ways to detect if the application has been launched in pre-warming mode? There are some references [here](https://twitter.com/_saagarjha/status/1466165623440883716?cxt=HHwWiICq8bn37tgoAAAA). But this has not be predictable for us yet.

Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can only try the following code:

```
BOOL isApplicationPreWarmed()
{
    return [NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment objectForKey:@"ActivePrewarm"] != nil;
}
```